# warning C6340: Mismatch on sign: '__int64' passed as _Param_(4) when some unsigned type is required in call to 'wsprintfW'

Tags: visual-c++

I keep getting this warning when I try to build the solution.I am new to VC++ please help.The code where it shows the warning is:

wsprintf( tempJournalFile, L"%s\temp_%I64u.bin",  CONFIG_DATADIR, time(NULL));

Comment: `time_t` (that `time()` returns) is defined as a signed integer. `%u` specifier expects a parameter of unsigned type. Hence the warning. Replace `%I64u` with `%I64d`.

Comment: Thank you . replacing %I64U with %lli also works,can either of the fixes be used?

Comment: Yes it can, with a modern enough VC version (if it works for you, then yours is). `%d` and `%i` are synonyms for `printf` et al. `ll` prefix is the synonym for (non-standard, Microsoft-specific) `I64`.